# Unable to launch scotchbox pro vagrant

Tags: vagrant, scotchbox

I'm struggling to install scotch box pro on my MacBook Pro running 10.14.6. I run vagrant up and this message appears in the terminal.

==> default: Detected mount owner ID within mount options. (uid: 1000 guestpath: /var/www)
==> default: Detected mount group ID within mount options. (gid: 1000 guestpath: /var/www)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by redownloading Scotch Box Pro not using the command line.